# Upload large files: Is resume option necessary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, large-files, swfupload

In my MVC project, I have to let the users upload large video files (size > 1 GB). There are many good options using Flash or Silverlight.

Since the file is large, **the upload process can be stalled** somewhere in between. Therefore, we have these design issues:

1. Does the upload addon have to support **pause/resume** option? I actually do not need the pause function, but the upload shall resume from where it has stalled, when the user restarts the process.
2. Does the user have to stay on the upload page, or keep it open and continue on some other page during the whole upload?
3. Keeping these two points in mind, what is your advice as an upload addon?

Edit: (Minor restrictions removed.)

More clearly:

> How do the swf-upload, SilverLight Uploader, etc. behave when the
>   transfer stalls? Shall the user start from scratch?

Comment: Can you clarify what the actual question is?

Comment: @Ryan: Thanks for comment. I have restated the title, and added a small summary. Please check the "edit" part.

Comment: @RyanKohn hello sir.....In my mvc3 web application I have designed a interface for upload video file upto 5GB. Will you please help me how to do this using any third party tool or any other technique ?

Comment: @dilipkumar1007 Please create a new question and someone out there should be able to assist with your query.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly let me re-confirm that uploading files of that size via `http` is not the best idea.

In case it is a must, I recommend using the `webdav api` and a handler code like in [this one](http://www.webdavsystem.com/client/programming/upload/resumable_upload).